# How to properly import library on Yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

In my project I am using imperavi-redactor library. But it seems it doesn't load properly.

When using the import() method, the library is properly loaded in the assets, but it doesn't work. If I modify the template I am using to manually load the css/js AFTER all other libraries, it works.
Here is the generated HTML:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/92dfc12c/redactor.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/f5a106d4/jui/css/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/f5a106d4/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/92dfc12c/redactor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/92dfc12c/lang/es_ar.js"></script>
<title>Create Notification</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="/themes/p35/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
  <link href="/themes/p35/css/mediaqueries.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <link href="/themes/p35/css/ie/ie8.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
  <script src="/themes/p35/js/ie/css3-mediaqueries.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/themes/p35/js/ie/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <!-- Slider -->
  <link href="/themes/p35/js/responsiveslides.js-v1.53/responsiveslides.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">

  <!-- Redactor -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/54ed052f/imperavi-redactor/redactor.css"/>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/themes/p35/js/jquery.ba-bbq.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/themes/p35/js/jquery-latest.min.js"><\/script>\
    <script src="/themes/p35/js/jquery-ui.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script>jQuery(document).ready(function($){ $('img').removeAttr('width height'); });</script>
    <script src="/themes/p35/js/responsiveslides.js-v1.53/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/themes/p35/js/jquery-mobilemenu.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/themes/p35/js/custom.js"></script>
    <!-- Redactor -->
    <script src="/assets/54ed052f/imperavi-redactor/redactor.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/54ed052f/imperavi-redactor/lang/es_ar.js"></script>

</head>
```

Notice how redactor.css, redactor.js and es_ar.js are included twice... The first time each file is included is because of using the regular import() method. The second time they are included is beacuse of manually modifying the template to include them.

I could forget about importing the module regularly, and just changing my theme to load required files all other libs, but I don't like it, and also it would be always loading a library that is only used in a few views.

Any idea of how could I manage to make the import() method work for me?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from your code whether you're already using it, but I'd personally recommend the Yii-redactor extension. It handles all the registration of script files for you, all you do it create a redactor widget.
See here http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/redactor/